# How do I use php_beautifier with PEAR Code Standards?

Tags: php, coding-style, pear, code-formatting, php-beautifier

How do I use php_beautifier with PEAR Code Standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`PHP_Beautifier_Filter_Pear`](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/docs/PHP_Beautifier/Filter/PHP_Beautifier_Filter_Pear.html) instead of the [default filter](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/docs/PHP_Beautifier/Filter/PHP_Beautifier_Filter_Default.html).

```
$oBeaut->addFilter('Pear',array('add_header'=>'php'));
```

Or from CLI

```
$ php_beautifier --filters "Pear(add_header=php)"
```

The PEAR filter will

> - Add 2 newlines after Break in switch statements. Break indent is the same of previous line
> - Brace in function definition put on a new line, same indent of 'function' construct
> - Comments started with '#' are replaced with '//'
> - Open tags are replaced with `<?php`
> - `T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO` replaced with `<?php echo`
> - With setting 'add_header', the filter add one of the standard PEAR comment header (php, bsd, apache, lgpl, pear) or any file as licence header.

Comment: and what about variable names? Thank you.

Comment: @thom the PEAR filter is a decorated Default filter. With the exception of the changes listed above, any beautifications of the default filter should apply. If neither PEAR nor Default filter beautify variables according to PEAR standard, you have to add that yourself somehow.

Comment: I have the same doubt: "What about local variables inside functions and methods:
$my_local_var or $myLocalVar?" found here: http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/standards.naming.php

Comment: @thom Like I said, if PHP_Beautifier does not do this out of the box, then you have to add it yourself somehow. Consider contributing any improvements you do back to the PEAR project.